# Naming a NuGet package through YAML

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

I have a yaml build on Azure DevOps for packing up and pushing a few `csproj` projects into a single NuGet package.

My challenge is that the name of the package is being named as the one of the projects. I know of the `nuspec` file, but I don't know if that will override my versioning mechanism and I would like to control my naming from a single place - my build file!

Can it be done?

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet pack'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    arguments: --include-source --include-symbols
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'    
    versioningScheme: byBuildNumber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this command `dotnet pack -p:PackageID=myId` so in YAML it would be:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "dotnet pack"
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: pack
    arguments: >
      $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/stackoverflow/52-nuget-packager/SampleApp.csproj
      --no-build
      -p:PackageId=myId
      --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
      -p:PackageVersion=2.1.0
      -p:Configuration=$(buildConfiguration)
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'off'
    outputDir: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

however to have this working you need to use custom command. But I'm not sure how it will behave when you have mulltiple projects to pack and I have no such example at hand. You can find [this topic](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11640) interested.